# Code is missing for service error Service Fabric

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to deploy a new service in to my service fabric cluster

I am sure I have created this in the same way as my other services.

I have manually sorted out the ApplicationManifest file that seems fine

However, when I try to run the local dev cluster VS crashes out with powershell error

```
Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType : The BuildLayout of the application in 
6>C:\SfDevCluster\Data\ImageBuilderProxy\AppType\Inspired.TradingPlatform.ServiceFabricType is invalid. Code is missing 
6>for service Inspired.TradingPlatform.TrayportApi.Primary.ServiceFabricPkg.
6>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
6>Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:251 char:9
```

This error is really unhelpful, it doesnt tell me anything about what code is missing

The rest of the error is

```
   Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationPathInImage ...
6>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [Register-Servic 
6>   eFabricApplicationType], FabricException
6>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RegisterApplicationTypeErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.RegisterApplicationType
```

Comment: Dig in the exception stack and post more details please, current details are of little use, you might be missing the code file / script, are you having any post / pre build events

Comment: I think I remember seeing this when i had a path to the executable wrong in my ServiceManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HiredMind thanks that was the issue!  My project was preferring x32 and even when changed to x64 was just going to debug when it should have been debug\x64 Thanks!

Comment: Nicely done! Can you please expand on this to help others who have the same problem? Also consider accepting your answer as it's resolved the issue.